# using laravel auth with different table

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

As previously asked I want to use  different table(clients) for auth.

I have allready edited some codes, but still I am not able to use auth method.

I've tried too many variations but, still can't login with auth it after user register.

`config/auth.php`

```php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ]


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Client::class,
        ],
```

client modal file.

```php
    class Client extends Authenticatable
    {

        protected $guard = 'client';


        public $timestamps = true;

        protected $fillable = [
            'email',
            'password',
            'fullname',
        ];


        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];

    }
```

clients migration file.

```php
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Controller

```php
    public function showRegister()
    {
        return view('pages.register');
    }

    public function doRegister(ClientRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $request->merge(['created_at' => Carbon::now()]);
        $request->merge(['password' => Hash::make($request->password) ]);

        $add = Client::create($validated);

        auth('client')->attempt($add);

        return redirect('my_profile')->with('success', 'success');
    }
```

After submit register form I get this error.

```
    Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
    Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::attempt() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\wamp64\www\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\HomepageController.php on line 117
```

when I change my attempt code like this, It returns null.

```php
    auth('client')->attempt([
        'email'=> $request->email,
        'password'=> $request->password
    ]);
```

Comment: Does  your user is getting registered successfully in table?

Comment: yes sir, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `user` is getting created successfully try this line.

```
auth('client')->login($add);
```

Remove this line

```
auth('client')->attempt($add);
```